# Strange error in kernel log

Tags: mac

When I run my application on MacBook, I can see in the kernel log:

```
AppleMCP89TMS::powerGatingUp(1)
```

Does anyone know what this is? Is this a hardware error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power Gating is the process of using transistors to physically cut off power to electronic components. Newer computer architectures do this as a way to save battery power by totally eliminating the 'leakage' in components that aren't doing anything. I don't know exactly what this log entry means, but I suspect that it's just a result of an automatic power management process and nothing to worry about (especially if your application activates any kind of peripheral hardware).